# Apache OpenNLP: How do I implement a dictionary based entity recognition?

Tags: apache, opennlp

I have already downloaded the jar files to eclipse.

http://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.5.3/apidocs/opennlp-tools/index.html

How do I do the following:

1.) Be able to add my own names and tags.
2.) Be able to get the names and tags that were in the dictionary.
3.) Configure between case sensitive and insensitive.

For example, let's say, I add the name "Mike Smith" with name tag "Author".

If I have text that has that name, it should be able to recognize that its there along with the tag.

Please give actual java code!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have asked a very similar question here:

[Is it possible to conduct 'Context Analysis' for precise entity extraction with OpenNLP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19638144/context-analysis-for-precise-entity-extraction)

general concensus is that its 2 steps, first to identify if your sentence contains Author, the second to find the name.

I too would like to do it in 1 step (where the analysis of the corpus includes the words within itself as a way to determine the context of the name)