# Is it possible to conduct 'Context Analysis' for precise entity extraction with OpenNLP?

Tags: text-mining, opennlp

Im wondering if opennlp can be used to extract very specific context when using the namefinder api.

For example, if i have two sentences:

> Jane Smith, 26, was taken into custody for stealing biscuits at her local Sainsburies.
>
> Jane Smith, 26, was awarded a medal of honour for bravery.

In this situation, i would like opennlp to detect not just the sentence structure (finding Jane Smith in both sentences), but also conclude that when the words 'custody', 'stealing' is used in the same sentence, then this gives a different context to the second sentence. Therefore if i train the first sentence to be '[START:offender] Jane Smith [END]' and second '[START:hero] Jane Smith [END]', there will be some decision at some point based on the words within the sentence i train.

I know Opennlp uses feature extraction (from what i've read it looks at sentence structure - i could be wrong here?), but i wonder if there is also some dictionary analysis as well, if i train enough of these sentences, will i eventually get good a good context split?

If there isnt, can you suggest any way forward (which is scalable)? I want to try and keep with Opennlp because of the license.

Comment: DocumentCategorizer seems to be related to what you are looking for. Though I wonder how good it will work if the document is just one sentence. http://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.5.3/manual/opennlp.html#tools.doccat

Comment: I'm happy to train many sentences if it will work. What you have posted is fine for determining if one sentence falls into different categories (im doing something similar with mahout), however this will be a step on top of entity extraction, it would be nice if perhaps the namefinder API can be extended to consider also the text (not just the sentence structure). Otherwise i first have to traina  model to pick up only those sentences which fall into my categories, and then to add entity extraction on top.

Comment: I don't think this comes out of the box with OpenNLP.